# Read file name from its part in powershell

Tags: powershell, text, filenames

I have a script that works with three files. Name of one of them is always the same, so it's set directly in the script code. Names of the other two are different each month. They look like this:

proemail vytvoreni_9.2017 2017-10-16.csv

proemail neaktivni_9.2017 2017-10-16.csv

Last 10 characters before extension is the date of creation, 9.2017 (in this case) defines for which month this report is relevant. But the date is all that is different, so I'm wondering if I can read the names of the files without using the Read-Host cmdlet to make the script ask for the file names when run.

Now I need to tell the script "read text from a file name, that starts with proemail vytvoreni_" (or "proemail neaktivni_" respectively). How can I do that? The last file name differs in the second word. I need the file names to be read without the extensions.

I hope it's understandable, what I need to achieve.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried so we can see where you're stuck?

Comment: Well I'm not exactly stuck, the script work perfectly well, I just want to make it easier to use. Now I use Read-Host cmdlet to get the file names to the script `$ReportAdded = Read-Host "File name of added users report"` and `$ReportRemoved = Read-Host "File name of removed users report"` which I'd like to replace by the procedure to get the file names automatically.

Comment: `Get-Content -File "C:\temp\proemail vytvoreni*"`? Caveat being if there are multiple files it will read them all. So as long as you can be sure or have check logic I don't see an issue here.

Comment: Hm, I don't see any -File parameter in Get-Content cmdlet. I have PS 5.1

Comment: try -Path instead

Comment: Doesn't work. I used it this way: `$ReportPridani = Get-Content -Path "$PSScriptRoot\proemail vytvoreni*"` and I got an error, that \proemail vytvoreni* does not exist. Obviously it doesn't understand the asterisk as a wildcard.

Comment: Get-ChildItem "PSScriptRoot\proemail vytvoreni*" | Get-Content

Comment: $string = 'proemail vytvoreni_9.2017 2017-10-16.csv'
$string.Split('_')[0]

Comment: `$ReportPridani = Get-ChildItem "$PSScriptRoot\proemail vytvoreni*" | Get-Content` does not read anything, the variable is empty. I tried even `$ReportPridani = Get-ChildItem "$PSScriptRoot\proemail vytvoreni*".ToString() | Get-Content`

Comment: Problem with the `$string.Split` is, that the part after the underscore is always different, so I can't put the file name in just like that.

Comment: Glad we got to answer in the end, but in future please post your full script (removing/obfuscating any sensitive parts) to get to a solution quicker - it's very hard to debug/suggest answers when you're only feeding us a line at a time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the files are in the directory equivalent to `$PSScriptRoot`, then this should work.

```
$ReportPridani = Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot | Where {$_.Name -like 'proemail vytvoreni*' -or $_.Name -like 'proemail neaktivni*'}
```

`Get-ChildItem` lists the files in the directory, `Where` filters them. You can include your third statically-named file here too, by adding `-or $_.name -eq 'static filename'` into the `Where {}` section, if it's in the same folder as the others.

Comment: This loaded all the content of the file, not its name.

Comment: Ok just remove Get-Content from the end (updated answer)

Comment: When I modified it like this, it works: `$ReportPridani = (Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot | Where {$_.Name -like 'proemail vytvoreni*'}).ToString()` But problem is, it reads the name including the extension. Later in the script I determine start and finish dates the script should work with based on last 10 characters of the name `$Datum = Get-Date -Date $ReportPridani.Split(".")[1].Substring($ReportPridani.get_Length()-10)`. The split method was not originally there, I added it there now, since the string contains extension.

Comment: But I get the error, that start index can't be greater than length of the string. Which it shouldn't be, the second string should be 15 characters long.

Comment: I realised, that now when I use the split by dots, the string I use for the date is ALWAYS 15 characters long, so now I can define the substring by simple number (5 in my case) and don't have to use the `get_Length` method. So the script works fine already. Thank you all guys.